# boxing unboxing

Tags: c#, .net, boxing, unboxing

I found the following code snippet while searching about boxing and unboxing in C#.

```
class TestBoxing
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int i = 123;

        // Boxing copies the value of i into object o. 
        object o = i;  

        // Change the value of i.
        i = 456;  

        // The change in i does not effect the value stored in o.
        System.Console.WriteLine("The value-type value = {0}", i);
        System.Console.WriteLine("The object-type value = {0}", o);
    }
}
/* Output:
    The value-type value = 456
    The object-type value = 123
*/
```

Over here it says that even though he value of i changes the value of o remains the same.If so then o is referencing to the value "123" and not i.Is it so?If o stored the value of i then when the value of I was changed the value of o would have changed too. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `// Boxing copies the value`

Comment: You need to distinguish between value type and reference type. Value type always get copied on assigned unless you use ref or out keyword when passing into a method. Reference types do not get copy but point to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or
>   to any interface type implemented by this value type. When the CLR
>   boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a System.Object and
>   stores it on the managed heap. Unboxing extracts the value type from
>   the object. Boxing is implicit; unboxing is explicit. The concept of
>   boxing and unboxing underlies the C# unified view of the type system
>   in which a value of any type can be treated as an object.

---

```
int i = 123;
// The following line boxes i. 
object o = i;
```

[image]

---

```
o = 123;
i = (int)o;  // unboxing
```

[image]

please read the [full article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Boxing:- process of converting from value type to reference type For example

```
int val = 10;
object Obj = val;
```

UnBoxing:- Its completely opposite to boxing Its the process of converting reference type to value type For example

```
int val2 = (int)Obj;
```